# php print pdf using php_printer.dll on windows serverside

Tags: php, pdf, printing

my job is to print pdf-files serverside on a windows-machine with xampp installed.
Now I´ve installed php_printer.dll and copied/written a test-script from [here](http://de3.php.net/manual/de/function.printer-open.php):

```
$printer = "\\\\SERVER\\PRINTER";
$file = "test.pdf";

if ($ph = printer_open($printer)) {

    // Get file contents
    $fh = fopen($file, "rb");
    $content = fread($fh, filesize($file));
    fclose($fh);

    printer_start_doc($ph, "TESTPAGE");
    printer_start_page($ph);

    // Set print mode to RAW and send PDF to printer
    printer_set_option($ph, PRINTER_MODE, "RAW");
    printer_write($ph, $content);
    printer_close($ph);

    echo "-> Job was sent to ".$printer;

} else {
    echo "-> Couldn't connect... ".$printer;
}
```

But it does not work with pdf-files; text-only is okay. If I print pdf-files, there are only incorrect chars on the paper :(
What can I do to print serverside pdf´s in php?
Any tips?

Regards, rumble